# Xamarin IOS launching external Apps

Tags: c#, xamarin, maps

Im trying to launch 3 map applications using an alert menu (Apple Maps, Waze, Google Maps). There is no problem clicking the option "Apple Maps", it diplays the address that i have but the other options doesnt launch the apps, just the app store. The code should display the app if its installed in the device (already installed waze, google maps, apple maps)

Controller Code

```
direccion.TouchUpInside += delegate {
            UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView () {
                Title = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("Seleccione la aplicación que desea utilizar", "")
            };
            alert.AddButton (NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("Apple Maps", ""));
            alert.AddButton (NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("Waze", ""));
            alert.AddButton (NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("Google Maps", ""));
            alert.AddButton (NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("Cancelar", ""));

            alert.Clicked += delegate (object a, UIButtonEventArgs b) {

                if (b.ButtonIndex == 0) {
                    string url = "http://maps.apple.com/?q=" + direccion.TitleLabel.Text;
                    url = url.Replace (" ", "%20");
                    url = Utils.LatinToAscii (url);
                    if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl (new NSUrl (url))) {
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (new NSUrl (url));
                        Console.WriteLine (url);
                    } else {
                        new UIAlertView (
                            NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("aviso", ""),
                            NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("error_al_abrir_mapas", ""), null,
                            NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString ("aceptar", ""), null).Show ();
                    }
                }

                if (b.ButtonIndex == 1) {
                    string url = "waze://?q=" + direccion.TitleLabel.Text;
                    url = url.Replace (" ", "%20");
                    url = Utils.LatinToAscii (url);
                    if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl (new NSUrl (url))) {
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (new NSUrl (url));
                        Console.WriteLine (url);
                    } else {
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (NSUrl.FromString ("http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106"));
                    }
                }

                if (b.ButtonIndex == 2) {
                    string url = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=" + direccion.TitleLabel.Text;
                    url = url.Replace (" ", "");
                    url = Utils.LatinToAscii (url);
                    if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl (new NSUrl (url))) {
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (new NSUrl (url));
                        Console.WriteLine (url);
                    } else {
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (NSUrl.FromString ("http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id585027354"));
                    }
                }
            };
            alert.Show ();
        };
```

Comment: I think it would launch the App Store if your `UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl` fails. Can you check if that is happening? You also have to add those URL schemes in your Info.plist so you have permission to check if they exist at runtime - have you done that?

Comment: Yes, it launches the app store if it fails, there is no problem with that. I tried to add this code to the info.plist but i dont know if its right.

<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>waze</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>

Comment: I don't think you need that first CFBundleURLTypes... Just start with LSApplicationQueriesSchemes... See [App Linked With iOS 9 section](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/) for more details. (I know that's for Object-C/Swift, but the knowledge is still correct).